# Update rank of all child elements on Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm having trouble updating the rank of an entire array at once on Firebase.

I have the following code:

```
var playersList = new Firebase('https://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com/players');

var rank = 1200;
function createNewPlayer(firstname) {
    var newplayer =  new Firebase('https://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com/players/' + firstname);
    newplayer.setWithPriority({first : firstname},rank);
}
```

I would like to do a `setPriority` for every element in `playersList`.

Comment: I'm afraid you would have to do it one by one. Do you want all to have rank 1200?  BTW there are no arrays in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to update the rank of each player in a list:

```
function updatePlayers() {
  playersList.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().setPriority(snapshot.getPriority()+1);
  });
}
```

In this snippet, I simply increase the value by 1.

There are no bulk operations in the Firebase API. But I doubt they would make things easier than the snippet above anyway.

http://jsbin.com/pikil/2/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution may be to simply store the players score or criteria for ranking as a priority. Then you may fetch them and order them as they arrive. For example, assuming we rank them by `points`:

```
var myUserId = 'kato';
var ref = new Firebase('https://INSTANCE.firebaseio.com/players/');
function updateMyPoints(newScore) {
   ref.child(myUserId).setPriority(newScore);
}

function fetchAndRankTopPlayers(callback) {
   ref.limit(100).endAt().once('value', function(snap) {
      var players = [];
      snap.forEach(function(ss) {
         players.push({id: ss.name(), score: ss.getPriority()});
      });
   });
}

fetchAndRankTopPlayers(function(list) {
    console.log('the 3rd place player is ' + list[2].id);
});
```

Also, check out the firebase [leaderboard example](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/leaderboard).